# Accurate evaluation of ${}_2F_1(-n, 1-x; 2; 2)$

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I want to evaluate accurately $f_n(x)={}_2F_1(-n, 1-x; 2; 2)$, where ${}_2F_1$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function. I am interested in the case with $x\in(0,2)$ and $n$ a natural number as large as possible. Fixed $n$, if one expands $f_n(x)$, it seems to consist of only positive coefficients (I don't know how to prove this), whose sum is equal to 1. However, I have tried myself a number of implementations and all of them are unstable for even rather small values of $n$. On the other hand, the existing comercial packages are not of much help either. For instance, in Matlab,

hypergeom([-400, 1 - 1.9], 2, 2)

returns -1.476649544606420e+10

and, in Mathematica,

Hypergeometric2F1[-400, 1 - 1.9, 2, 2]

returns 1.25542*10^58

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, including how to generate them, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mathematica seems to do better if you force it to do some symbolic work first. For instance, the Mathematica expression `Simplify[Hypergeometric2F1[-400, 1 - x, 2, 2]] /. x -> 1.9` (that is, simplify ${_2}F_1(-400,1-x;2;2)$ to obtain some degree-$400$ polynomial, and then evaluate at $x=1.9$) gives the far more believable result `224.8712571980159`.

Comment: I suggest more precision. Try `Hypergeometric2F1[-400, N[1-19/10, 50], 2, 2]`.

Comment: As a followup on @Somos, the main point seems to be that Mathematica does just fine so long as you use a _rational_ input and then ask for an approximation. So `N[Hypergeometric2F1[-400, 1 - 19/10, 2, 2]]` also works just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, they are very useful. However, I would like to design a code to evaluate the functions myself. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Use contiguous relations. There's a linear relation between $f_n(x), f_{n-1}(x), f_{n+1}(x)$ which could be used to evaluate the function starting from small $n$. See Wikipedia page for explicit forms for the contiguous relations

Comment: Yuriy S, could you please add the Wikipedia link?

Comment: @User, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Gauss'_contiguous_relations

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see why these relationships could be useful. In my case, $b$, $c$ and $z$ are always fixed, but the relationships involve changing always more than one parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Using the information in [OEIS sequence A008309](https://oeis.org/A008309) I found that
$$ {}_2F_1(1-n, 1-x; 2; 2) =  \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=k}^n x^{k-1}2^{j-1}{n-1 \choose j-1}S_1(j,k)/j! $$
where $S_1(.,.)$ is the Stirling number of the first kind.
If you use the definition of the Hypergeometric function
then you get
$$ {}_2F_1(1-n, 1-x; 2; 2) =  \sum_{k=0}^n
  \frac{2^k(1-n)_k (1-x)_k}{k! (k+1)!} $$
where $(.)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol and $\,n>0.\,$ With any sum of numbers
**not** all the same sign you may have to be careful about possible
[loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).
For $\,0<x<2\,$ the signs in the sum alternate with the maximum absolute value
ocurring at around $\, k = 2/3n.\,$ If $\,n\,$ is large then you need to use
enough precision to account for loss of significance.

For more practical advice I suggest reading [DLMF Hypergeometric function 15.19](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.19) "Computation".

Comment: Since $n$ is natural, the signs of $(1-n)_k$ always alternate. In fact, this is the main obstacle I found when writing a piece of code myself.